# Learning material for Websphere MQ Clusters

Tags: ibm-mq, theory, high-availability

What are some good books for learning about Websphere MQ clusters? Material on messaging systems in general was easy to come by, but I can't find anything useful on the net to understand the fundamentals of MQ clustering.

To top that, since IBM does MQ clustering kinda differently ( I've heard ) from others ( if at all there's anyone else out there ) I need material that's specific to Websphere MQ. What little info I got only confused me further. I'm having a tough time understanding how connections are established to a cluster if it's just a logical grouping only known internally to itself, what exactly the repository info of the cluster contains and how to setup a cluster for high availability etc.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay looks like I found a red book of some sort

http://www-05.ibm.com/e-business/linkweb/publications/servlet/pbi.wss?CTY=US&FNC=SRX&PBL=SC34-6589-00#